# How to extract the below pattern from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string which looks like below.

```
{(firstName1,lastName1,College1,{(24,25)},{(Street,23)},City1,Country1)}
```

I need to extract the details/values from the above and add them to a list. By details I mean:

```
 ["firstName1","lastName1","College1","24","25","Street","23","City1", "country1"]
```

How can I achieve the above? I tried the below method but not sure how to get all curly braces and brackets into the pattern.

```
private static String flattenPigBag(String pigdata) {
    String s = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*)}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pigdata);
    while (m.find()) {
        s = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("answer : " + s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It is not clear which data you need to extract, but since your data is CSV at least at the top level, I might be for first splitting by comma.  If you expect nested data, then regex may not be the right tool here, you should use a parse instead.

Comment: @Thrasher I have edited the question. Please have a look again

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen splitting would incur lot of string processing. After splitting for commas, I need to split the brackets of different types and so on. A pattern matching solution would be better.

Comment: @mayooran You should probably be using a parser here because the brackets are nested.  And regex _also_ requires a lot of string processing, don't think that just because it fits in a single line that it does not require processing.

Comment: all your doing is stripping `{,(,),}` you dont need a regex for it

Comment: @may the "string processing overhead" would be measured in microseconds. It's not a big deal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Comma-separated records into String Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312120/java-comma-separated-records-into-string-array)

Comment: @mayooran -- Do you need the field values for further processing? If so, please see my answer below.

Comment: @leeyuiwah thanks mate! I will try it during this weekend and let you know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] parts = str.replaceAll("}|\\{", "").split(",");
```

Comment: In expected output, OP has given `and` instead of comma. I don't know how that works.

Comment: @gur I think OP was just using English, not actual output.

Comment: when comes to regex, master Bohemian always be the number one :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you forced to use a pattern?  If not, feel free to use this.

```
private static List<String> flattenPigBag(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll("[(){}]", "").split(","));
}
```

Output:

```
[firstName1, lastName1, College1, 24, 25, Street, 23, City1, Country1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need to extract the individual fields for further processing.  So here is what I would do.  In my test program I just print out the fields, but I imagine in your program you may take those field values and use them somehow (e.g. apply them to some setters of a Java object)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatchingWithNamedCaptureGroup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\{(\\("
                + "(?<firstName>[^,]*)"
                + ",(?<lastName>[^,]*)"
                + ",(?<college>[^,]*)"
                + ",\\{\\("
                + "(?<num1>\\d*)"
                + ",(?<num2>\\d*)\\)\\}"
                + ",\\{\\((?<street>[^,]*)"
                + ",(?<streetNum>\\d*)\\)\\}"
                + ",(?<city>[^,]*)"
                + ",(?<country>[^,]*)"
                + "\\))\\}";
        String input
        = "{(firstName1,lastName1,College1,{(24,25)},{(Street,23)},City1,Country1)}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.find()) {
            String firstName    = m.group("firstName");
            String lastName     = m.group("lastName");
            String college      = m.group("college");
            String num1         = m.group("num1");
            String num2         = m.group("num2");
            String street       = m.group("street");
            String streetNum    = m.group("streetNum");
            String city         = m.group("city");
            String country      = m.group("country");
            System.out.println(firstName
                                + "," + lastName
                                + "," + college
                                + "," + num1
                                + "," + num2
                                + "," + street
                                + "," + streetNum
                                + "," + city
                                + "," + country
                                );
        } else {
            System.err.println("Does not match!");
        }

    }

}
```

The output of this program is this:

```
firstName1,lastName1,College1,24,25,Street,23,City1,Country1
```

Comment: That regex, my eyes!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated my regex to use named-capture group to make the code easier to read and maintain.